# how to set any class as my startup object in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

i have three classes each having Main fuction inside a single application.i have to set any class as per my requirement as strtup object in c#.it is not providing all three classes as startup object.is there any way to do this?

Comment: The method signatures need to be **static void Main(string[] args)** I'm assuming your classes don't have something like that in them, but without your code, its very hard to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: multiple entry points into a program that can all be used at run time? I'm pretty sure that isn't possible

Comment: i am not using multiple entry point in program.

Comment: i am not using multiple entry point in program.my quesion is about multiple     having multiple classes with entrypoint(i.e.Main function) but choosing one of them as startup oject in visual Studio-2012

Answer (score 1):

Yes, provided your `Main()` method has the correct signature, you can specify the class as a compiler option:

```
/main:class
```

see this link for full instructions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3eht538.aspx

Comment: Assuming it has a main method with the proper signature, yes, otherwise this won't work. Its the same as setting it on the property page but the property page will let you know if you can't select that class because it doesn't have a proper method for Main in it.